# Scala - Recursive view bounds

Tags: scala

How do I get scala compiler to look for an implicit view recursively?

```scala
type Expression = () => String

implicit def constant(s: String): Expression = () => s

implicit def evaluation[A <% Expression](exprs: Seq[A]): Expression = () => exprs match {
  case "concat" :: args => args.map(_.apply()).mkString
}

Seq("concat", "foo", "bar")() // This works
Seq("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", "baz"))() // No implicit view available from java.lang.Object => () => String.
```

I understand that the last sequence has the common type `Object` which has no implicit view, but how can I define a type-safe one without resorting to dynamic pattern matching of `AnyRef`?

Tried in scala 2.9.2

Comment: shouldn't it be `Seq("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", "baz")())()` instead of `Seq("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", "baz"))()`? (note the extra parenthesis after the inner Seq)

Comment: @gourlaysama no, the point of the implicit view is that I don't have to evaluate sequences manually, but rather get recursive evaluation implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The type-inference figured out you have a `Seq[Any]` because of the mixed contents. The easiest solution is to help the compiler and tell it you have a `Seq[Expression]`

```
Seq[Expression]("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", "baz"))()
```

### Edit

This is how you could solve it with tuples:

```
type Expression = () => String

implicit def constant(s: String): Expression = () => s

implicit def evaluation[A <% Expression, B <% Expression, C <% Expression](
  exprs: (A, B, C)): Expression = 
  () => exprs match {
    case ("concat", arg1, arg2) => arg1() + arg2()
  }

("concat", "foo", "bar")()                      //> res0: String = foobar
("concat", "foo", ("concat", "bar", "baz"))()   //> res1: String = foobarbaz
```

Comment: This works only for a single nesting level. This doesn't compile again `Seq[Expression]("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", Seq("concat", "baz", "aaa")))()`. I'm looking for a recursive solution.

Comment: Well the problem is that now the second sequence is inferred as type `Any`. So this would do it: `Seq[Expression]("concat", "foo", Seq[Expression]("concat", "bar", Seq("concat", "baz", "aaa")))()`. If you want a more clean solution you might want to take a look at other collections. `Tuple` in this case (where you have pairs of 3) would work better.

Answer (score 0):

I also wondered why the scala compiler couldn't figure out that the inner Sequence was an expression - I figured, you simply forgot some brackets - here they are:

```
Seq("concat", "foo", Seq("concat", "bar", "baz")())() // added inner brackets
```

**Edit**

I see your point however - this also does not work:

```
val x: Expression = Seq("concat", "foo", "bar") // This works
val y: Expression = Seq("concat", "foo", x) // No implicit view available - again
```

so - here also it is necessary to provide the brackets for x.

Comment: oops - just saw the comment above in the question - well that was the correct answer

Comment: I have added the `Tuple` variant to my answer, maybe that is more satisfying?